# SWT delayed events

Tags: java, events, swt

I am inserting an **SWT** `Control` inside each row of `Table` via a `TableEditor` and I am seeing that sometimes GUI adjustments on the child control happen with ~1 second of delay.

As an example, pick a `Button` (FATAL logs are `Table`'s events, ERROR logs are `Button`'s event):

[image]

I can see that e.g. on table initialization, re-sorting, new-row, usually the list of events that are called on a table's row is:

```java
TableItem.IMECOMPOSITION
TableItem.ERASEITEM
TableItem.MEASUREITEM
TableItem.PAINT
(~1 looooong second passes)
Button.PAINT
```

This is in line with [what I knew](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html) (well, not the button thing), but I would like to understand:

- *why* is the event on the child-button delayed?
- *how* to systematically synchronize the PAINTing of all children of an SWT control/table/tree/[...].

Comment: Usually events aren't delayed, I suspect it is your code that causes the delay. Can you post the relevant parts, or even better a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Thanks @RüdigerHerrmann for your comment: that's a first direction. I'll try to provide a snippet!